# How can I use a type defined in another .ml file in OCaml?

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

Assume I have two `.ml` files: `A.ml` and `B.ml`.

---

In `A.ml`, I have

```
type my_type = {id_ary : int array; sz_ary : int array};;
```

---

In `B.ml`, I have

```
let test_my_type {id_ary;_} = id_ary.(0) <- 10;;
```

---

Then I compiled them like this

```
ocamlc -linkpkg A.ml B.ml -o C
```

But complier gives such an error: `Error: Unbound record field label id_ary`

It seems that `B` can't use the type `my_type` from `A`.

**What should I do?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `open A` to the beginning of B.ml

Also just a heads up, it will be more convenient to build your code with: `ocamlbuild B.native`
(You will have to clean your code directory however)

Answer (score 6):

It's worth noting that you can just use `A.id_ary` in `B.ml`. Using `open` is a convenience to avoid repeating `A.`. However, `open` is also a rather drastic thing to do as it merges the two namespaces. I personally try to avoid using `open` except for a few very fundamental modules in my projects.

Recent OCaml versions have a "localized" open with two notations:

```
# String.(length "abc");;
- : int = 3
# let open String in length "abc";;
- : int = 3
```

These are much less drastic, and I would prefer them to the global `open`.

Comment: This is true and important to understand. `open A` is probably correct for the OP's case however because it seems like all he wants to do is test module `A`.

Comment: ahh, ok, I can use like `let test_my_type {id_ary;_} = A.id_ary.(0) <- 10;;`

Comment: could you please have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876228/strange-module-loading-issue-in-ocaml?