# Strange module loading issue in OCaml

Tags: functional-programming, ocaml

I have two files: `myUnionFind.ml` and `myUnionFind_test.ml`. Both files are in the `same directory`.

### myUnionFind.ml

```
open Batteries

module type MyUnionFindSig = 
sig

  type union_find

  val print_array : 'a array -> unit
  val create_union : int -> union_find
  val union_weighted : union_find -> int -> int -> unit
  val is_connected_weighted : union_find -> int -> int -> bool
end;;


module MyUnionFind : MyUnionFindSig =
struct 
  let print_array ary = print_endline (BatPervasives.dump ary);;

  type union_find = {id_ary : int array; sz_ary : int array};;

  let create_union n = {id_ary = Array.init n (fun i -> i); 
            sz_ary = Array.make n 1};;

(* weighted quick union find *)

  let find_root ary i = 
    let rec find j =
      if ary.(j) = j then j
      else  find ary.(j)
    in
    find i;;

  let union_weighted {id_ary;sz_ary} p q = 
    let root_p = find_root id_ary p in
    let root_q = find_root id_ary q in
    if sz_ary.(root_p) < sz_ary.(root_q) then begin
      id_ary.(root_p) <- id_ary.(root_q);
      sz_ary.(root_q) <- sz_ary.(root_q) + sz_ary.(root_p)
    end 
    else begin
      id_ary.(root_q) <- id_ary.(root_p);
      sz_ary.(root_p) <- sz_ary.(root_p) + sz_ary.(root_q)
    end;;


let is_connected_weighted {id_ary;_} p q = (find_root id_ary p) = (find_root id_ary q);;

end
```

### myUnionFind_test.ml

```
open Batteries

let uf2 = MyUnionFind.create_union 10;;

MyUnionFind.union_weighted uf2 0 3;;
MyUnionFind.union_weighted uf2 1 4;;
MyUnionFind.union_weighted uf2 4 3;;
MyUnionFind.union_weighted uf2 2 8;;

MyUnionFind.print_array uf2.MyUnionFind.id_ary;;

BatPervasives.print_bool (MyUnionFind.is_connected_weighted uf2 0 3);;
```

---

I tried

`ocamlfind ocamlc -package batteries -c myUnionFind.ml`. It worked, I can see `myUnionFind.cmi` and `myUnionFind.cmo`.

Then I tried to compile `myUnionFind_test.ml` via

`ocamlfind ocamlc -package batteries -c myUnionFind_test.ml`.

It gives this error:

> File "myUnionFind_test.ml", line 3, characters 10-34: Error: Unbound
>   value MyUnionFind.create_union

---

**I can't figure out why. I have defined `create_union` in module `MyUnionFind`, but why it can't be found?**

Comment: If you do not intend to use the `MyUnionFind_sig` signature for anything else than the `MyUnionFind` module itself, move the sig to `myUnionFind.mli` and remove the module signature coercion in `myUnionFind.ml`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You define a module in a module (your myUnionFind.ml is a module).

So in your test file, you have to open your module like this:

```
open Batteries
open MyUnionFind (* Here !*)
let uf2 = MyUnionFind.create_union 10;;

MyUnionFind.union_weighted uf2 0 3;;
MyUnionFind.union_weighted uf2 1 4;;
MyUnionFind.union_weighted uf2 4 3;;
MyUnionFind.union_weighted uf2 2 8;;

MyUnionFind.print_array uf2.MyUnionFind.id_ary;;

BatPervasives.print_bool (MyUnionFind.is_connected_weighted uf2 0 3);;
```

or prefix each call like:

```
let uf2 = MyUnionFind.MyUnionFind.create_union 10;;
```

If you just define a module in myUnionFind.ml and you don't want to have two modules like previously, you can just create a .ml and .mli file like this:

```
 (* myUnionFind.mli *)
 type union_find  = {id_ary : int array; sz_ary : int array}

 val print_array : 'a array -> unit
 val create_union : int -> union_find
 val union_weighted : union_find -> int -> int -> unit
 val is_connected_weighted : union_find -> int -> int -> bool

 (* myUnionFind.ml *)
 type union_find = {id_ary : int array; sz_ary : int array};;

 let print_array ary = (* ... *)
 let create_union n =  (* ... *)
 let union_weighted r p q = (* ... *)
 let find_root ary i = (* ... *)
```

**Be careful, if you have a reference to `id_ary` field, you have to put it in the module signature**

Comment: I don't understand why mine is module in module. in my case, how do I write so that it is just one level of module, instead of module inside another?

Comment: The only way to have one level of module is to write it as `mli` and `ml`?

Comment: Also how to put `id_ary` field inside the signature, without exposing the entire `union_find` implementation?

Comment: In OCaml, a file is already a module, so yes if you want to have one level of module is to have a .ml (and a .mli) file.

Comment: For id_ary, you can have something like a "getter": `val id_ary: union_find -> int_array` and the code `let id_ary t = t.id_ary`. So in your test file you'll do something like `MyUnionFind.print_array (MyUnionFind.id_ary uf2);;`

Answer (score 1):

OCaml gives you one level of module for free with each file. So your `myUnionFind.ml` has a module within this free module. To avoid this, declare everything at the top level of the file. Then you have just one module, with the same name as the file.

Comment: If I declare everything at the top level of the file, then how do I control its sig? I don't want every functions to be exposed.

Comment: Use the .mli file to control the exposed interface.