# Unbound type constructor OCaml with different file

Tags: ocaml

I am working on a project in OCaml but I have a problem when I compile. I have a "unbound type constructor Door.position". I compile with a makefile.
door.mli :

```
module Door : sig
  type position
  type state
  type door

  val create  : position -> state -> door
  val getState    : door -> state
  val setState    : door -> state -> door
  val getPosition : door -> position
  val setPosition : door -> position -> door
  val isOpen      : door -> bool
end;;
```

The file contains the error, case.mli:

```
module Case : sig
  type case

  val create  : int -> int -> case
  val getDoor : case -> Door.position -> Door.door
end;;
```

I don't have idea where the problem is.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Strange module loading issue in OCaml](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14876228/strange-module-loading-issue-in-ocaml)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In OCaml all code that is put in file `foo.ml` (or `foo.mli`) is implicitly packed into the module `Foo`. In your case if you have `door.mli` that contains module named `Door`, that means, that from the outside it can be accessed only as `Door.Door`, i.e., you need it qualify with a name of file.

In short, that means, that in your `mli` file you don't need to write `module Door : sig`, since it is already implicitly there. Just write your signature.